# What is the difference between "characterized by" and "characterized in"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

The electrode is **characterized by** the chloride.

The electrode is **characterized in**, that the chloride comprises acid compounds.

Comment: This isn't a contrast between "*by*" and "*in*" but rather "*by*" and "*in **that***". You can look up "*in that*" in a good dictionary. (After your edit you've misplaced the comma and broken up the fixed phrase "*in that*" which will only add to your confusion.)

Comment: @DanBron: I did edit it by adding a coma.

Comment: Yes, as I said above, you've misplaced the comma and thereby invalidated the original author's intent, which will only confuse you further. You simply need to look up "*in that*", understand why and how it's used, and all will become clear.

Answer (score 1):

*Characterized in* is nothing.

*In that* means *because*.  See http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in+that, meaning 33.

*Characterized by* is good, but not in your proposed sentence.  For example, *to be characterized by low chloride concentration* means *to have a low chloride concentration as a typical quality or feature*.  See http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/characterize

Answer (score -1):

"by" can be used to indicate **an agent that performs the characterization**:

> [Preface to Social Economics: Economic Theory and Social Problems](https://books.google.ca/books?id=hHXuGC8zLjUC&pg=PA41&dq=%22be%20characterized%20by%20that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=F-kcVYi9EMyrNpCtg7gE&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAzgU#v=onepage&q=%22be%20characterized%20by%20that%22&f=false) ... - Page 41
>   John Maurice Clark, ‎Moses Abramovitz, ‎Eli Ginzberg - 1936
>
> We must become far better informed and surer of our own intentions
>   before our dealings with the machine can be **characterized** by
>   **that confidence which marks the bargaining of equals.**

"in" can be used for:

"**characterized in [a certain] /way/manner/**, when talking about **a manner of characterization**

> [Disjunctivism: Contemporary Readings](https://books.google.ca/books?id=a8KehfGHBUMC&pg=PA132&dq=%22be%20characterized%20in%20that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0-YcVdeuC8SkNvC2gtAD&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22be%20characterized%20in%20that%22&f=false) - Page 132 Alex Byrne, ‎Heather
>   Logue - 2009
>
> Presumably, however, there may be available a more direct
>   characterization of the second disjunct, and in a totally explicit
>   version of the theory it would indeed be **characterized in that
>   better way.**